# How to add a new package to source control with RTC

Tags: java, spring, rational-team-concert

I have a project with several packages and i created a new one. I can't deliver the package because RTC can't see it.

What can i do ? It is `invisibile` and can't be seen to " pending changes " . I'm using `eclipse`

Thank you

I tried to right click -> team -> check in or deliver and nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

To add a new package to source control with [Rational Team Concert (RTC)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/engineering-lifecycle-management-suite/lifecycle-management/6.0.3?topic=overview-rational-team-concert) in [Eclipse](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/engineering-lifecycle-management-suite/lifecycle-management/6.0.2?topic=samples-installing-rational-team-concert-clients), you wuold need to make sure Eclipse recognizes the new package as part of the project under source control and then manually adding the package to source control if it is not automatically detected.

```bash
Eclipse Workspace
│
└───Project (RTC Source Control)
    │
    ├───Source Folder
    │   │
    │   └───Existing Package
    │   │
    │   └───New Package (Not visible in RTC)
    │
    └───Other Folders
```

So first, confirm that the new package is located within a source folder of the Eclipse project that is under RTC source control. If it is outside, it will not be detected.

Then:

- Right-click on the project or the specific source folder in Eclipse.
- Select **Refresh**.
- After refreshing, right-click again and navigate to **`Team -> Check for Local Changes`**. That action prompts Eclipse to scan for changes not yet recognized by RTC.

If the new package is still not appearing in the "Unresolved" or "Pending Changes" view, you might need to add it manually. Right-click on the new package. Select **`Team -> Add to Source Control`**.
Review any `.jazzignore` in the folder/ parent folders of your package, in case one of those `.jazzignore` prevents the package content to be consider for versionning.

After adding it to source control, the package should now appear in your "Pending Changes". Right-click on the package or the changes and select **Check-in** to commit the changes locally. Then, select **Deliver** to push your changes to the server.

After delivering, verify in the RTC client or web interface that the new package has been added to the repository.

If the package still does not show up, make sure your Eclipse project is correctly associated with an RTC component and that your view configuration in RTC is set to show all changes, not just those against the latest baseline.